# Is there way to create a symbol's array like string with %w?

Tags: ruby, string

I can create a array of strings by `%w(foo bar)`.
Is there similar way to create a array of symbols?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do as below :

```
%i(foo bar)
```

It is available since Ruby2.0.0.

Check out the their official [*News*](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/NEWS#L18)

> Added `%i` and `%I` for symbol list creation (similar to %w and %W).

Comment: It is also described in the [official documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings).

Comment: Interesting.  I noticed that `%s(foo bar)
 => :"foo bar"` as well.  Thanks for the link, @toro2k.